# Nemiver showing only ASM code

Tags: c++, debugging

As stated , whenever I try to debug my executable , it shows only Disassembly , no source code is visible for debugging. I try to choose 'show source code' from menu , nothing happens.

[image: Nemiver]

Answer (score 1):

I had your same issue, you have to compile the program in debug mode (for example adding the -g parameter when you call gcc if you are programming in c)

Comment: Ah yes I solved it too but didn't put an answer , anyways thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you compiled your source files without using -g parameter (as quoted by @stefano) , nemiver or any other debugger can only see the assembly version of your program and hence fails to show source code in your case.

You can see more such flags by either opening a man page [example](http://www.dsm.fordham.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi.pl?topic=g++) or specific c++ options [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html)

Comment: Thanks for providing those links , and I'll definitely see those man pages :)